# does flutter remove the unused classes ,methods... when building the release app?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I'm wondering if one thing, for example, if we use a package, let's named **X**, and inside of it there are 3 methods :

```
void method1() {}
void method2() {}
void method3() {}
```

and in my whole project, I used just the `method2()` of them, when building the release app, does the whole package will be included inside the release app, or just the used methods and the unused ones are removed?

or the question is, should I care about extracting or researching the minimal useful package for me, or I am good with using any large package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I know, unnecessary parts will be removed by tree-shaking.

Based on  [build-modes#release](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/build-modes#release)

> The build is minified and tree shaking has been performed.

The tree shaking method remove the dead code.

So while you only use `method2()`, others unused methods will be removed.

Comment: but, are the packages included in this tree-shaking, or just the project code files, because this seems to be so general

Comment: Once I watched some flutter video(Humpday Q&A/AMA), they(I think simon) said, don't worry about using packages, unnecessary parts will be removed. If i get the link I will include it here. Also you can check [this for now](https://medium.com/flutter/optimizing-performance-in-flutter-web-apps-with-tree-shaking-and-deferred-loading-535fbe3cd674), So the answer is yes

Comment: the links you refer to mentions tree shaking for web apps, but not for native (android/ios) apps..?